# JS text variable always showing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've seen about 20 or more posts on the subject, but they either don't make sense to me or are slightly different.

Ive been scratching my head on this for ages. Searching for answers provides a ton of conflicting advice but nothing I have seen yet works. Ive boiled the problem down to this simple form. If I enter data in the box and click the button the alert is always undefined. Could somebody explain why please and also how I can assign the variable properly and test by pushing it out on an alert?

Thanks in advance.

Code follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                var jsPostcode = document.getElementsByName("pcode").value;
                alert(jsPostcode);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="login">
        <table>
            <td><input style="width: 80px" name="pcode" type="text" /></td>
            <td><button>OK</button></td>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a collection of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you could use the attribute selector [`$('[name=pbode]')`](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) to select the element, and then get it's value by using the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var jsPostcode = $("[name=pcode]").val();
    alert(jsPostcode);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="login">
  <table>
    <td><input style="width: 80px" name="pcode" type="text" /></td>
    <td><button>OK</button></td>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByName` returns array. So, update this line,

`var jsPostcode = document.getElementsByName("pcode").value;`

to

`var jsPostcode = document.getElementsByName("pcode")[0].value;`

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName` returns a collection of all elements.

You need to access the first item of this collection.

To do this update your line to `document.getElementsByName("pcode")[0].value`.

It is the same way you access the first item of an array in js.

You need to update your code to the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var jsPostcode = document.getElementsByName("pcode")[0].value;
    alert(jsPostcode);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="login">
  <table>
    <td>
      <input style="width: 80px" name="pcode" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>OK</button>
    </td>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer docs -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

elements = document.getElementsByName(name)
**elements** is a live NodeList Collection 
**name** is the value of the name attribute of the element.
Hence we are accessing first item in the array getElementsByName("pcode")[0]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){


var jsPostcode = document.getElementsByName("pcode")[0].value;

alert (jsPostcode);

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head>
</head>

<body>
                <form name="login">
                        <table>
                                <td><input style="width: 80px" name="pcode" type="text" /></td>
                                <td><button>OK</button></td>
                        </table>
                </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `documentGetElementById();` and give them id for better catch.